# Can I utilize 2 Leviton LTB60 timers in 3 way configuration to control a single exhaust fan

Tags: timer

I am wanting to connect 2 Leviton LTB60 timers to control a single inline exhaust fan that evacuates 2 separate bathrooms.
Can I accomplish this without the use of a Leviton Vizia remote controller?
Can I not connect the timers in the same wiring configuration as a simple 3 way circuit to control a light?
Thank you

Comment: I suggest you restate the question as "Can I utilize 2 Leviton LTB60 timers to control a single exhaust fan that serves two rooms?".   I don't want to edit your question so heavily but that is what you mean, and if you ask it that way the answer can be "Yes".  Perhaps @ThreePhaseEel will modify his answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

### 3-way control isn't what you want

The other answer is correct in that two LTB60s can't be connected together to provide 3-way timer control of a device.   However, that's not what you're after here, either -- instead, you want ORing control, where having either timer on will make the bath fan go.  As a result, you *can* do this with the devices you have -- simply wire their switched-hots (red terminals) in parallel, while leaving their traveler (yellow/red) terminals unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot accomplish dual control without using the Leviton Vizia VP0SR remote control unit.  If you look at the product specifications for the LTB60 series at:

[Leviton LTB60 Specification Sheet](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/G-8264D_Timer_Switches_Spec_Sheet.pdf)

The show the following connection diagram:

[image: Hookup Drawing]

This is how you accomplish remote control of this device.

Using two LTB60s in parallel (somehow) would fail because they are not designed to operate that way.